# Checkmark (Wingdings font) not displayed on pdf export

Tags: jasper-reports

The checkbox appears correctly on previewing the report, but doesn't show up when exported to pdf.

```
<staticText>
 <textElement textAlignment="Center">
  <font fontName="Wingdings" size="18"/>
 </textElement>
 <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
</staticText>
```

The checkmark has been copied from a word document to here.

Wingdings is a inbuilt font within Jasper so I guess no need to add it as a font extensions.

I am using Jaspersoft Studio 5.6

This is how I have chosen Font Windings, so I assume its inbuilt in Jasper.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Wingdings is built-in within Jasper. You can confirm that by trying to find it in **Advanced** Properties tab in *PDF Font Name* property. In XML view you can put:

```
<font fontName="Wingdings" pdfFontName="Wingdings"/>
```

but during export you'll find out that Wingdings font is not found. Also `pdfFontName` is deprecated, so you shouldn't use it anyway.

It looks like you have to use Font Extensions. Here's my working example:

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="96ccfacd-cf1e-44b2-ae0f-69c863141ba7"/>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Wingdings"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
</staticText>
```

And Font Extensions config:

```
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Wingdings">
        <normal>fonts/wd/wingding.ttf</normal>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

EDIT:

To clarify: I mean *PDF Font Name* shown below

[image: PDF Font Name drop-down list]

I must say I don't know what are these fonts below *ZapfDingbats*, but fact of the matter is that this is the last font on the list that is available in PDF export.

Excerpt from `com.itextpdf.text.FontFactoryImp` class as a proof:

```
ArrayList<String> tmp;
tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add(FontFactory.COURIER);
tmp.add(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD);
tmp.add(FontFactory.COURIER_OBLIQUE);
tmp.add(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE);
fontFamilies.put(FontFactory.COURIER.toLowerCase(), tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
tmp.add(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD);
tmp.add(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE);
tmp.add(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE);
fontFamilies.put(FontFactory.HELVETICA.toLowerCase(), tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add(FontFactory.SYMBOL);
fontFamilies.put(FontFactory.SYMBOL.toLowerCase(), tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN);
tmp.add(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD);
tmp.add(FontFactory.TIMES_ITALIC);
tmp.add(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLDITALIC);
fontFamilies.put(FontFactory.TIMES.toLowerCase(), tmp);
fontFamilies.put(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN.toLowerCase(), tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add(FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS);
fontFamilies.put(FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS.toLowerCase(), tmp);
```

Comment: Hi, I have added wingdings font as shown in above screenshot. Since its available in the dropdown, is my assumption correct that the font is inbuilt?